# How to solve a problem about unique column in MySQL

Tags: unique

I am having problem with this MySQL error, if it is an error, - Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available. - My query is

SELECT
INTERVAL a.seconds SECOND + CONCAT(
DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d'),
' ',
TIME_FORMAT(CURTIME(), '%H:%i:%s')) difdate
FROM
diffdate a

time_id is my unique and primary column

Please help. How can I resolve this problem?

Thank you.